# sed append multiple lines of text to end of file

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a file add.txt with multiple lines of text that would need to append to end of another file, ,config.txt

add.txt

```
line 100
line 101
line 102
```

config.txt

```
line 97
line 98
line 99
```

After appended, config.txt become

```
line 97
line 98
line 99
line 100
line 101
line 102
```

How can be achieved by reading add.txt with sed command and append to config.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done with `cat` as per @Marius_Couet [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728158/273579).

you can however use `sed`.

```
sed -i -e '$r add.txt' config.txt
```

where

- `-i` tell `sed` to edit in place.
- `-e` execute a command
- `$r add.txt` from last line, read add.txt

---

sed option is mostly usefull if you do other `sed` operations

```
sed -i -e 's/.../.../' -e '....' -e '$r add.txt' config.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can append to a file using `>>`

Doing so should work :

```
cat add.txt >> config.txt
```